# Angular material toolbar - Material behavior

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material, material-design, angular-material2

I am using Angular and Angular Material for a project. Since this project's design is based on Material, I am using Angular material for it's components.

I have created a toolbar via `<mat-toolbar>` and a tab list via `mat-tab-group`. And the page looks as follows:

[image: Basic view]

This is all ok. The first tab also contains a list **And this is where the problem starts..**

---

### The Problem

When you normally scroll down the list, according to [material design](https://material.io/design/components/tabs.html#behavior):
[image]

the top bar should scroll away and the tabs should be on top. This is not the standard behavior of Angular Material and I am wondering if this is possible to recreate?

I've recreated the default behavior in a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1qvt33).

---

### My versions

- Angular: `7.2.6`
- Angular Material: `7.3.3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've implemented it by using the [**headroom.js**](https://wicky.nillia.ms/headroom.js/) library. I do not own this library, but I've used it in several projects and it worked perfectly.

Install:

```
npm install headroom.js --save
```

Firstly, what we need is to set up the `.mat-toolbar` and `.mat-tab-header` elements to `position: fixed`. `.mat-toolbar` will be fixed to the top of the document (`top: 0`), and `.mat-tab-header` will be fixed below the toolbar (`top: 56px` - because 56px is the default height of the toolbar):

```css
.mat-toolbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 9;
}

.mat-tab-group {
  padding-top: 48px;
}

.mat-tab-group ::ng-deep .mat-tab-header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 56px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

The css code above is provided at component level, and that's why I need to use `::ng-deep` selector. We also need to give some padding for `body`:

```css
body {
  padding-top: 56px;
}
```

Then, we'll attach Headroom.js to the `mat-toolbar` element. The library will add a specific css class to this element on scroll down, and another css class on scroll up. But we also need to update the position of the `mat-tab-header` accordingly:

```html
<mat-toolbar color="primary" role="toolbar" aria-label="toolbar" #toolbar>
  ...
</mat-toolbar>

<mat-tab-group backgroundColor="primary" color="accent" mat-stretch-tabs #tabgroup> 
  ...
</mat-tab-group>
```

```ts
@ViewChild('toolbar') toolbar: MatToolbar;
@ViewChild('tabgroup') tabgroup: MatTabGroup;

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  const toolbarEl = this.toolbar._elementRef.nativeElement;
  const tabHeaderEl = this.tabgroup._elementRef.nativeElement;

  const headroomOptions = {
    onPin : () => {
      tabHeaderEl.classList.remove('headroom--unpinned');
      tabHeaderEl.classList.add('headroom--pinned');
    },
    onUnpin : () => {
      tabHeaderEl.classList.remove('headroom--pinned');
      tabHeaderEl.classList.add('headroom--unpinned')
    }
}; 

  const headroom = new Headroom(toolbarEl, headroomOptions);
  headroom.init();
}
```

We also need the following styles for the classes that are added by Headroom.js:

```css
.mat-toolbar.headroom {
  will-change: transform;
  transition: transform 200ms linear;
}

.mat-toolbar.headroom--pinned {
  transform: translateY(0%);
}

.mat-toolbar.headroom--unpinned {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}

.mat-tab-group ::ng-deep .mat-tab-header {
  will-change: transform;
  transition: transform 200ms linear;
}

.mat-tab-group.headroom--pinned ::ng-deep .mat-tab-header {
  transform: translateY(0%);
}

.mat-tab-group.headroom--unpinned ::ng-deep .mat-tab-header {
  transform: translateY(-56px);
}
```

**Stackblitz demo**:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gqhwcr

Answer (score 0):

Using your existing [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1qvt33?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css), Add this to your **app.component.ts**:

```
.mat-tab-group{height: 100%;position: fixed; width:98vw;}
.mat-toolbar.mat-primary { width:98vw; }
```

Add this to your **styles.css**:

```
body { margin:1vw !important; }
```

the key to the effect which you're looking for is `.mat-tab-group{height: 100%;position: fixed;} ... but you'll see that the **mat-group** will be shorter than the **mat-toolbar** which looks kinda ugly... so we set them both to the same width... but now we got another issue, the margin is weird, that is because the body is set to a margin of 8px, so finally we override the absolute number 8px with 1vw... so it looks pretty.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Hi Akaber, this is almost what I am looking for, the result of your changes: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jcydhx

But this makes both the toolbar and the tabs fixed to the top, where the toolbar should scroll away when the list is scrolled down, where the tabs should scroll to the top and stay there (see the effect here: https://material.io/design/components/tabs.html#behavior, in the 'scrolling' section)

Comment: once the user scrolls down by more than 104px (height of mat-toolbar and mat-group), we need to do: `.mat-toolbar { display:none; }`

Comment: We may need more help on your comment here, looking for the community to help us https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55015895/material-design-android-like-behavior-on-a-web-application

Answer (score 0):

I got a bit confused about your problem but if you want to stick the tab header to top when it scrolls down.

Add the below code to your existing [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1qvt33) CSS file. These may definitely work.

```
.mat-tab-group .mat-tab-header
{
  position: sticky;
  top:0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your awnser, but this doesn't achieve what I want. I improved my question, maby this clarifies my question better.