# Material design (Android like) behavior on a web application

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design

**Scenario**

We got a `mat-toolbar` and a `mat-tab-group` - the behavior we need is like the GIF below i.e. when we scroll down, the `mat-tab-group` (Cats in the gif below) is scrollable and the `mat-toolbar` (Pets in the gif below) hides away, only to show up again after we scroll back up.

[The code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sa6zjz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

[image]

**Approaches i tried:**

1. Tried to use the scroll event, but unable to ascertain if the scroll was up or down because the `offsetHeight` and `offsetTop` numbers didn't change. `offsetTop` & `offsetHeight` change when the complete window scrolls, the values didn't change with our scroll which is inside the `mat-tab-group`.
2. Tried an observable to the mouse scroll, which works on the overall page, but stops capturing the scroll within our `mat-list`

**Question:**

- How to capture the scroll inside the `mat-tab-group` ?
- If this is not the correct way to achieve it, looking for guidance on the correct approach
- the GIF was taken from [Material Design standard](https://material.io/design/components/tabs.html#behavior)

Comment: I've posted an answer at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61561048/1135971.

Comment: nicely done @andreivictor - if you refer to that answer as an answer here, I'd be glad to mark it as accepted

Comment: thank you! I don't know if posting an answer that refers my own answer is a good practice on SO. I would prefer to not post it. The another question is linked to this one and I think that people will find it easily.