# How can i set Toolbar to fixed position using angular material design?

Tags: angular, angular-material

How can i fix toolbar position to fixed using angular material? i am tried with position fixed but it not worked for me.Can please suggest how can i do this.

Here is my code:

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between" class="fixed-header header-shadow" style="width:100%;position:relative">
  <mat-toolbar   color="primary" fxFlexFill role="banner" class="header-style header-shadow">
    <mat-toolbar-row>
      <div>
          <a  mat-button  routerLink="#"  routerLinkActive="active" (click)="opened=!opened"><mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror mat-icon notranslate mat-icon-no-color ng-star-inserted" role="img">menu</mat-icon></a>
          <a  mat-button  routerLink="#"  routerLinkActive="active">{{application_title}}</a>
      </div>
      <div fxShow="true" fxHide.lt-md="true" class="example-fill-remaining-space">

          <a  mat-button  routerLink="/customer-list"  routerLinkActive="active">Customers</a>
          <a  mat-button  routerLink="/customer-create">Create Customer</a>
          <a  mat-button  routerLink="/login">Login</a>
      </div>
      <div>
          <a  mat-button  routerLink="#"  routerLinkActive="active"><mat-icon>notifications</mat-icon></a>
          <a  mat-button  routerLink="#"  routerLinkActive="active" fxShow="true" fxHide.lt-md="true">Prem Kuma Pallinti</a>
          <a  mat-button  routerLink="#"  routerLinkActive="active" fxShow="true" fxHide.lt-md="true"><img aria-hidden="true" src="C:/Users/Prem/Desktop/FinalApp/images/man-avater.png"></a>
          <a  mat-button  routerLink="/login"><mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror mat-icon notranslate mat-icon-no-color ng-star-inserted" role="img">more_vert</mat-icon></a>
      </div>

    </mat-toolbar-row>


    </mat-toolbar>
    <main>
    <router-outlet  style="margin-top: 80px;"></router-outlet>
    </main>

</div>
```

[code [image: code]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wclff.png)

Comment: does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54958584/angular-material-toolbar-material-behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove `style="width:100%;position:relative"`.
And add css for

```
.fixed-header: {
   width:100%;
   position: fixed;
   top:0;
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just add the class sticky using position attribute to sticky

```
.fixed-header: {
  position:sticky;
  position:-webkit-sticky; /* For macOS/iOS Safari */;
  top: 0; /* Sets the sticky toolbar to be on top */
  z-index: 1000; /* Ensure that your app's content doesn't overlap the toolbar */

}
```

I tried @TanNguyen method but my app content is overlapping the toolbar